# Customize wavelength in pavo

Tags: r, colors, spectrum

I am using pavo package in R to extract color variables and ran in to the problem that I would like to calculate chroma for custom ranges, but I can't seem to find the code that let's me modify default wavelength ranges for the function

```
    summary(lizspec)
```

This returns 23 variables, all default functions, but all calculated within default ranges, which I would need to change.
Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[`summary.rspec`](http://rafaelmaia.net/pavo/reference/summary.rspec.html) provides `wlmin` and `wlmax` arguments for this specific purpose:

```r
library(pavo)
data(sicalis)
summary(sicalis, wlmin = 500, wlmax = 600)
```